# Initialize JUnit test class's base class constructor with parameters at the time of instance creation (before running the tests)

Tags: java, junit

I am currently writing a test framework which uses JUnit to execute some tests. As a part of this framework I will be creating the JUnit Request object and run the tests using JUnit Core object. What I need is a way to initialize the test class's parent class with some parameters  so that the base class's constructor can initialize the local variables of the base class and hence those can be used in the tests present in the test class.

I am not able to find any good information on how to do that. All help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Garrett,
I have completed this, I used a static variable and initialized it using a static method invocation. I will put in the code in sometime.